# How do I format the output of SQL query row-wise

Tags: shell, awk, mysql, text-formatting

Below query gets me the value in a variable called `result`

```
result=`mysql --user=root --password=password1 deployment --host=localhost -Ns -e "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(url_timestamp), '%M %Y') month, COUNT(url_timestamp) counter FROM mytable WHERE status='PRODUCTION' and url_timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR GROUP BY month, LAST_DAY(url_timestamp) ORDER BY LAST_DAY(url_timestamp);"`

echo $result
```

Output:

```
November 2019 43 December 2019 556 January 2020 111 February 2020 221   ....    November 2020 98
```

Note: The output of SQL query as visible in sql client is well formatted. However, when assigned to shell variable the row wise formatting is lost.

My Expected output is:

```
November 2019 43 
December 2019 556
January 2020 111
February 2020 221
   ....    
   ....
November 2020 98
```

Can you please suggest ?

Comment: It's an issue with the way you use `$result` unquoted with `echo`, not how the data is stored in the variable. But do you really need to store the result in a variable if you just want to output it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[quote the variable](/q/131766/72456):

```
echo "$result"
```

and [better to use `printf`](/q/65803/72456):

```
printf '%s\n' "$result"
```

and also better to use this type of [command-substitution `$(...)`](/q/126927/72456) instead.